# How to save HTML to my XML and then display said HTML using XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to save some HTML to an XML file and then output that HTML via XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://mywebsite.com/sites/default/files/lesson_resource.xsl"?>
  <lesson_resource name="Verbs" type="vocabulary" help="&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:24px&quot;&gt;Ask your teacher about this:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;  &lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Example:&lt;/u&gt; &lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000&quot;&gt;Verbs&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;  &lt;p&gt;I &lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000&quot;&gt;like &lt;/span&gt;school.&lt;br /&gt; I &lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000&quot;&gt;eat &lt;/span&gt;pizza.&lt;br /&gt; I&lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000&quot;&gt; go&lt;/span&gt; home.&lt;/p&gt;  &lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Description:&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/p&gt;  &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:#FF0000&quot;&gt;Verbs &lt;/span&gt;are doing words.&lt;/p&gt; ">
</lesson_resource>
```

At the moment I have this working in Chrome, but Firefox just prints the actual HTML as it doesn't support disable-output-escaping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="lesson_resource">
            <div class="page">
                <img src="../pictures/logo.png" style="height:100px; padding-right:20px;"/>
                <h3 style="display:inline-block;"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></h3>
                <div style="float:right;">http://www.mywebsite.com</div>
                <div><xsl:value-of select="@help" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></div>
            </div>      
        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should I be storing the HTML differently?

Comment: Ideally you would store it as XHTML as nodes and not as escaped markup, then you could easily process the nodes with XSLT.

Comment: Or, by extension, could you please explain how you arrive at the escaped string as an attribute value?